# Program sleeps for way more time than intended- Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a memory game in Python Tkinter. After two cards are flipped, the program is supposed to sleep for a second and then flip over the cards. It doesn't sleep for one second though, it sleeps for about ten seconds. My code isn't finished by the way so that's why it lacks game features.
Why is it sleeping for way more time that intended?
My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice
from time import sleep

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Disney Princesses Memory Game")
width = screen.winfo_screenwidth()
height = screen.winfo_screenheight()
screen.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
screen.configure(bg="#e0bce5")

title = Label(screen, text="Memory Game", font=("David", 50, "underline", "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
title.place(x=400, y=20)

images_list = [
    PhotoImage(file="images/aurora.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/belle.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/cinderella.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/jasmine.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/mulan.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/rapunzel.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/snow white.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/tiana.png")
]

buttons_list = []
chosen_images = []
flipped = []
num_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
card = PhotoImage(file="images/card.png")
count = 0
no_press = False


def choose_images():
    counter = 0
    for num in range(16):
        chosen_image = choice(images_list)
        counter += 1

        chosen_images.append(chosen_image)


def replace_card(c, d):
    global flipped
    global count
    global no_press

    if no_press is True:
        return

    count += 1

    if count > 2:
        count = 0
        no_press = True
        screen.after(2000, reset)
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(image=chosen_images[d])
        flipped.append(buttons_list[c][d])


def sleep_secs():
    global no_press
    sleep(1)
    no_press = False
    reset()


def reset():
    global card
    if no_press is True:
        screen.after(2000, sleep_secs)
    else:
        for element in flipped:
            element.configure(image=card)


choose_images()
x = 100
y = 250
for i in range(2):
    buttons_list.append([])
    for j in range(8):
        a = Button(screen, image=card, command=lambda i=i, j=j: replace_card(i, j))
        x += 100
        a.place(x=x, y=y)
        buttons_list[i].append(a)
    y += 100
    x = 100

screen.mainloop()
```

Updated code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Disney Princesses Memory Game")
width = screen.winfo_screenwidth()
height = screen.winfo_screenheight()
screen.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
screen.configure(bg="#e0bce5")

title = Label(screen, text="Memory Game", font=("David", 50, "underline", "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
title.place(x=400, y=20)

images_list = [
    PhotoImage(file="images/aurora.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/belle.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/cinderella.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/jasmine.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/mulan.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/rapunzel.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/snow white.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/tiana.png")
]

buttons_list = []
chosen_images = []
flipped = []
num_list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
card = PhotoImage(file="images/card.png")
count = 0
no_press = False


def choose_images():
    for num in range(16):
        chosen_image = choice(images_list)
        num_list[num] += 1

        if num_list[num] > 2:
            num += 1
            continue
        else:
            chosen_images.append(chosen_image)


def replace_card(c, d):
    global flipped, count, no_press

    if no_press is True:
        return

    count += 1

    if count > 2:
        count = 0
        no_press = True
        sleep_secs()
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(image=chosen_images[d])
        flipped.append(buttons_list[c][d])


def reset():
    global card, no_press
    for element in flipped:
        element.configure(image=card)


def sleep_secs():
    global no_press
    screen.after(2000, reset)
    no_press = False


choose_images()
x = 100
y = 250
for i in range(2):
    buttons_list.append([])
    for j in range(8):
        a = Button(screen, image=card, command=lambda i=i, j=j: replace_card(i, j))
        x += 100
        a.place(x=x, y=y)
        buttons_list[i].append(a)
    y += 100
    x = 100

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the whole logic but:  `replace_card` waits 2 seconds before calling `reset`.  Which waits 2 seconds before calling `sleep_secs` which sleeps for 1 second before calling `reset`.  This means (at least) 5 seconds delay between clicking the button and the second call to `reset`.   Am I right to assume there only  needs to be one 2 second delay during the cycle.  `sleep` with a tkinter GUI is best avoided too.

Comment: @Tls Chris, I noticed that and fixed it. I'll update the code

Comment: Does it work as expected now?  I can't run the code as I don't have the image files required.

Comment: @Tls Chris, I'm experiencing a strange bug. sometimes it flips the cards when it's supposed to and sometimes it just doesn't flip them at all

Comment: I'm not sure.  Try printing `count` and `no_press` in 'replace_card' and see if it's always what you expect.  They are the main variables that drive the sequence of events.

Comment: @Tls Chris, ok, I'll try

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this section:

```
def sleep_secs():
    global no_press
    sleep(1)
    no_press = False
    reset()


def reset():
    global card
    if no_press is True:
        screen.after(2000, sleep_secs)
    else:
        for element in flipped:
            element.configure(image=card)
```

Sleep_secs uses reset in its definition and reset uses sleep_secs in its definition. This seems like it would create an immediate issue.

Comment: In reset, I used sleep_secs because it only delays a certain part of the program instead of the whole program. When I remove reset from sleep_secs, the issue still remained

Comment: BTW, it is better to use `.after` instead of  `time.sleep()`

Comment: @PCM, ok thank you! I made sure to replace it to .after. But, there is one issue: when I run the code, sometimes when I flip two cards, the program flips back the cards after two seconds as it should, and other times, it just waits forever